# How to add variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, sum

Python noob here. I'm trying to add a set of input variables defined in an 'if' statement and whenever I try to find the sum it will just display the values inline. For example, when a, b, c, and d equal 5, perimeter = 555...

```
shape = raw_input("Is the plot a (q) quadrilateral or (t) triangle?")
if shape.lower() == "q":
    a = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'a'?")
    b = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'b'?")
    c = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'c'?")
    d = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'd'?")
elif shape.lower() == "t":
    a = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'a'?")
    b = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'b'?")
    c = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'c'?")
else:
    print "Please enter 'q' for quadrilateral or 't' for triangle."

if shape.lower() == "q":
    perimeter = a + b + c + d
elif shape.lower() == "t":
    perimeter = a + b + c
else:
    print "Please make sure you enter numbers only."

print perimeter
```

Comment: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread22164.html

Comment: You're missing an `int()` for the addition.

Answer (score 2):

`str` values can be added to each other much like numbers. The `+` operator you use works fine, but concatenates values for strings. The result of `raw_input` is a string (`str`), so that's why you'd see `'555'` in stead of 15. To sum numbers, use `int()` to coerce the values to numbers before adding them up:

```
try:
    a = int(raw_input('gimme a number'))
except ValueError as e
    print 'that was not a number, son'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It definitely helped though I wish I had a better way to clean it up. Oh well though, heres to being a noob!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `raw_input` actually Is an int():

```
shape = raw_input("Is the plot a (q) quadrilateral or (t) triangle?")
if shape.lower() == "q":
    try:
        a = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'a'?")
        b = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'b'?")
        c = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'c'?")
        d = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'd'?")
        perimeter = int(a) + int(b) + int(c) + int(d)
    except ErrorValue as e  
        print "Please make sure you enter numbers only."

elif shape.lower() == "t":
    try:
        a = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'a'?")
        b = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side 'b'?")
        c = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side '
        perimeter = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
    except ErrorValue as e  
        print "Please make sure you enter numbers only."
else:
    print "Please enter 'q' for quadrilateral or 't' for triangle."
```

Answer (score 0):

for variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, use `input(prompt)` instead of `raw_input(prompt)`.
`raw_input` returns a string, 
but `input` returns the console input evaluated as a python literal. (As of right now, you're
concatenating strings, not adding integers).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a good design. What if you want to add more shapes, hexagon, octagon and so on. You can actually use a dict to store shape mapping to number of sides. You don't have to write multiple if statements for each shape. You will have to do less type checking and you could use python builtin function sum to return the parameter. Go on now and try the following:

```
d = {'q': 4, 't': 3}

shape = raw_input("Is the plot a (q) quadrilateral or (t) triangle?\n")

if shape.lower() not in d:
    print "Please enter 'q' for quadrilateral or 't' for triangle."

else:
    sides = []

    for i in range(0,d.get(shape.lower())):
        side = raw_input("What is the length in feet of side " + str(i+1))
        try:
            sides.append(int(side))
        except ValueError:
            print "Integer value only"

    print sum(sides)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a dictionary.

```
sides = {'a':0,'b': 0,'c': 0,'d': 0}
perimeter = 0

shape = raw_input("Is the plot a (q) quadrilatral or (t) triangle?: ")
if shape.lower() == "q":
    for side, length in sides.iteritems():
        sides[side] = input("What is the length (in feet) of side %s?: " % side)
        perimeter+=int(sides[side])

elif shape.lower() == "t":
    sides.pop("d",None)
    for side, length in sides.iteritems():
        sides[side] = input("What is the length (in feet) of side %s?: " % side)
        perimeter+=int(sides[side])
else:
    print "Please enter 'q' or 't'."

print "Perimeter is: %d" % perimeter
```

I figured a dictionary would be easier to use.  Might be much cleaner, rather than repeat yourself.